# Influxdb 2 - how to get schema of a bucket?

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

How can i get a schema / list of existing fields, tags and measurements in particular bucket? I want to achieve this with using InfluxDB API or influxdb-client-js package in my JS app. Can it be done with proper query? Are there other options? Currently I'm using InfluxDB 2.2.0.

Comment: Here you are official documentation - https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/explore-schema/

Answer (score 0):

The [schema](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/influxdata/influxdb/schema/) package in Flux allows you to introspect your data for this information.